# TFS 2012 new workflow states does not show up in board configuration

Tags: tfs

I modified the Agile template's workflow, and is working fine, the new states are usable. I wanted to add new columns to the board on the web interface, but no luck, the new statuses are not selectable, only the factory ones.

Are the user-created statuses available for mapping?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow this description: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh739066.aspx

You need to configure `<TaskWorkItems category="Microsoft.TaskCategory">` values, so that your new states will be shown, e.g. `<State value="YourNewState" type="InProgress" />`

Comment: Sorry for not pointing out, but I'd like to modify the story board. This one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/02/01/customizable-kanban-swim-lanes.aspx . When I modify the CommonConfiguration.xml and want to import it, I get this error: Line: 32 Position: 11 - The 'type' attribute is invalid - The value 'Todo' is invalid according to its datatype 'StateFieldEnum' - The Enumeration constraint failed."

Comment: The type can only be "Proposed", "InProgress"or "Complete", these are to order the states on the board. If Todo is the new state you want to see, I would suggest this: `<State value="Todo" type="Proposed" />`

Comment: Thanks, this worked! TaskWorkItems added new column to taskboard (which is nice to know), but I also found, that adding values to RequirementWorkItems solves my question: I can select the workflow statuses which I added recently. I do not see the big picture yet, but this works now. Thanks!